# exporting Angular 4 service as array of injectables

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I know there is the following way of defining injectable services in Angular 2/4 (correct me if I am wrong somewhere, please):

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    ...
}

export const someServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  SomeService
];
```

What is the purpose of it? It injects a service with `@Injectable` without the array. AFAIK it is used for exporting specific implementation of a service (am I right?) but what's the benefit here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think you are mistaken ed you dnt need these lines `export const someServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  SomeService
];`

Comment: @Rahul Singh Sorry, I didn't get it. I mean I can remove the array, add the service class to `providers` in a `NgModule` and it will inject it. So why do I need the array? It is taken from examples from ng--book 2

Comment: Probably there was some other purpose

Comment: @Skeptor Well, in fact I haven't found any other usages across the project. So it seems to be like missing, to be deleted?

Comment: How is the service added to providers ?

Comment: @Skeptor `providers: [ SomeService  ]`

Comment: then I dont know

Comment: @Skeptor thank for suggestion at least:)